# Deprecation Warning for Quota, how to fix?

Tags: 22.04, quota

I am getting a deprecation warning, when I install quota and turn it on.

Ubuntu 22.04.03 Server

```
root@nfs2: apt install quota linux-image-extra-virtual -y
root@nfs2:/home/# quotacheck -u /home
root@nfs2:/home/# quotaon -v /home
quotaon: Your kernel probably supports ext4 quota feature but you are using external quota files. Please switch your filesystem to use ext4 quota feature as external quota files on ext4 are deprecated.
/dev/sdb1 [/home]: user quotas turned on
```

I have googled and haven't found a way to use the kernel quota feature.  Can someone help with either how to use the kernel version or the implications of continuing to use external quota.

Comment: I suspect it's just a matter of enabling usrquota for the filesystem using `tune2fs` - see for example [How to enable journaled quota on Debian 11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687877/how-to-enable-journaled-quota-on-debian-11)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to steeldriver, here is the solution.

```
umount /home
tune2fs -O quota /dev/sdxx
mount -a
quotaon -va
repquota /home
```

I found I had to reboot the server to make this take effect. Maybe there is a different way, but it seemed like a good thing to do anyway.